# User info in URI without password

Tags: http, url

I know that URI supports the following syntax:

```
http://[user]:[password]@[domain.tld]
```

When there is no password or if the password is empty, is there a colon?

In other words, should I accept this:

```
http://[user]:@[domain.tld]
```

Or this:

```
http://[user]@[domain.tld]
```

Or are they both valid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current URI standard ([STD 66](http://tools.ietf.org/html/std66)) is RFC 3986, and the relevant section is [3.2.1. User Information](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2.1).

There it’s defined that the *userinfo* subcomponent (which gets followed by `@`) can contain any combination of

- the character `:`,
- percent-encoded characters, and
- characters from the sets *unreserved* and *sub-delims*.

So this means that both of your examples are valid.

However, note that the format `user:password` is **deprecated**. Anyway, they give recommendations how applications should handle such URIs, i.e., everything after the first `:` character should not be displayed by applications, unless

> the data after the colon is the empty string (indicating no password).

So according to this recommendation, the *userinfo* subcomponent `user:` indicates that there is the username "user" and no password.

Comment: Thanks for the details and sources. I changed the accepted answer since this one is more complete.

Answer (score 1):

This is more like convenience and both are valid. I would go with `http://[user]@[domain.tld]` (and prompt for a password.) because it's simple and not ambiguous. It does not give any chance for user to think if he has to add anything after `:`